# Docker swarm route only when replica has finished starting

Tags: docker, routes, containers, docker-swarm

I have set up a docker swarm config that starts a java webserver image replicated x times. Now, the servers take it's time to start up (~40seconds) while the container itself is started quickly.

The problem is, docker starts routing to containers as soon as they are up, without knowing if the service inside the container is ready to serve requests, which in my case it is not immediately

What is the idiomatic way to configure docker swarm so, that it only routes to containers where the server is accepting requests?

Answer (score 1):

So there is a healtcheck section for the deployment of the compose file which one can use to make sure a container is healthy or not.

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3482/monitoring/health"]
  interval: 10s
  timeout: 5s
  retries: 3
  start_period: 1m
```

This will do it and make sure a container will be used first if the health api returns a valid response.

Comment: Can you add the `docker service` command version of this?