# Does docker swarm mode start replicas simultaneously or wait until each one finishes?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, confluence

I'm attempting to use `docker swarm` and `docker service` to deploy Confluence Data Center. However, the [Atlassian documentation for the clustering part](https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/adding-and-removing-data-center-nodes-659783919.html) gives this warning:

> You should only start one node at a time. Starting up multiple nodes simultaneously can cause serious failures.

What is the default startup policy for `docker swarm` service replicas? Do they all start simultaneously, or one after the other? If one after the other, how does it decide that one is done starting?

Comment: Based on this [somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62822362/2125392), I suspect it's one after the other, and that it's based on a health check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default docker swarm **create** the replicas at same time, but **update** one replica at time (rolling update). As far as I know, you can't control the creation but you can create an application with **one replica** and then update it:

```
docker service create --replicas 1 --name apache httpd:alpine
sleep 60 # one minute
docker service update --replicas 2 apache
sleep 60 # one more minute ...
docker service update --replicas 3 apache
```

This is safe because the existing replica is untouched if you don't change any parameter other then `--replicas`.

If you want to **update** the replicas one at time you can use `--update-parallelism`, and go even further controlling the time between each update replica with `--update-delay`:

```sh
docker service update apache \
--image nginx:alpine \
--update-parallelism 1 \
--update-delay 10s
```

Comment: Oh my god, you're right! This is only for "replicated-job" mode, sorry I'll edit fixing.

Comment: The only option is create the service with one replica, and then update it.

Comment: Edited including and update example. Please, always take a look on `--help` output, like: `docker service --help` or even with `docker service create --help` and other actions.